# Ubuntu crashing all the time

Tags: bluetooth, crash

I just started using Ubuntu about a month ago. It has worked smoothly until now. Now my PC is crashing all the time. I went in the folder /var/crash to see if there is anything unusual. This was in the folder.

ls -al /var/crash:

```
total 63504
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Απρ  16 14:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Μαρ  30 12:48 ..
-rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie  8715931 Απρ  13 23:02 _opt_microsoft_msedge_msedge.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   121927 Απρ  11 18:48 rtbth-dkms.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Απρ  11 18:48 rtbth-dkms.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Απρ  11 18:49 rtbth-dkms.0.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie  3716323 Απρ  16 14:01 _usr_bin_file-roller.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 gdm      whoopsie   730048 Απρ  11 18:34 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.125.crash
-rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie 51716198 Απρ  12 22:49 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_opera_opera.1000.crash
```

(I have been trying to fix my Bluetooth in the last few days, which I did not accomplish and the files seem pretty familiar)

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz
    
free -h :
                      total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
        Mem:          7,7Gi       2,0Gi       3,1Gi       534Mi       2,5Gi       4,8Gi
        Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
    


sysctl vm.swappiness:
vm.swappiness = 60
    
swapon -s:
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2

sudo lshw -C memory:
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Insyde
       physical id: 0
       version: F.19
       date: 05/06/2019
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 13MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 6MiB
       capacity: 6MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 11
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0,4 ns)
          product: RMSA3260NA78HAF-2400
          vendor: Ramaxel Technology
          physical id: 0
          serial: 11C1552E
          slot: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR Synchronous [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a141c000-a141dfff memory:a1422000-a1422fff

ls -al /var/crash:
total 63504
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Απρ  16 14:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Μαρ  30 12:48 ..
-rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie  8715931 Απρ  13 23:02 _opt_microsoft_msedge_msedge.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   121927 Απρ  11 18:48 rtbth-dkms.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Απρ  11 18:48 rtbth-dkms.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Απρ  11 18:49 rtbth-dkms.0.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie  3716323 Απρ  16 14:01 _usr_bin_file-roller.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 gdm      whoopsie   730048 Απρ  11 18:34 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.125.crash
-rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie 51716198 Απρ  12 22:49 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_opera_opera.1000.crash


lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1         7:1    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop2         7:2    0 399,4M  1 loop /snap/obs-studio/1284
loop3         7:3    0  91,4M  1 loop /snap/p3x-onenote/138
loop4         7:4    0 248,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop5         7:5    0  65,2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop6         7:6    0  61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop7         7:7    0 129,3M  1 loop /snap/teams/7
loop8         7:8    0 169,6M  1 loop /snap/spotify/58
loop9         7:9    0 129,8M  1 loop /snap/teams/6
loop10        7:10   0  61,9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1376
loop11        7:11   0  54,2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop12        7:12   0 164,8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop13        7:13   0 295,7M  1 loop /snap/vlc/2344
loop14        7:14   0  44,7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15534
loop15        7:15   0  43,6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
nvme0n1     259:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:3    0   238G  0 part /
```

lspci -nnk:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller [8086:3e34] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [8086:3ea0] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [103c:8532]
00:12.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller [8086:9df9] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller [8086:9ded] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 RAM memory [0500]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM [8086:9def] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM [103c:8532]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9de0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:9db0] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #10 [8086:9db1] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 [8086:9db4] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9d84] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller [103c:8532]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9dc8] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9da3] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller [8086:9da4] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller [103c:8532]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    DeviceName: Realtek Gaming GBE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8532]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix BC501 NVMe Solid State Drive 512GB [1c5c:1327]
    Subsystem: SK hynix BC501 NVMe Solid State Drive 512GB [1c5c:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

uname -r:

```
5.13.0-40-generic
```

after installing rtl8821ce-dkms,

dkms status:

```
rtbth/3.9.6: added
rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
```

sudo dmesg | grep -i hci:

```
[    0.676761] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.676770] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.676785] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.676798] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.676801] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.676811] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.676824] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.862771] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
[    0.865484] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.865492] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.866574] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000009810
[    0.866759] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.866761] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.13.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.875336] ahci 0000:00:17.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 2 ports 6 Gbps 0x3 impl RAID mode
[    0.875341] ahci 0000:00:17.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf pm clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
[    0.875822] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.875826] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.875829] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    0.875869] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.875870] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.13.0-40-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.882058] scsi host0: ahci
[    0.882234] scsi host1: ahci
[    1.207499] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.487603] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[ 1905.257593] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[ 2125.196327] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
```

Comment: What were you doing when it crashes? If it kernel panicked, what error/message did it give you? What, if any, changes did you make to the Bluetooth files?

Comment: I had just firefox , edge and spotify open nothing special. It didnt give me any error messages. For bluetooth it said/ says  "Plug in dongle to use bluetooth" so i basically followed these instractions: https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms/blob/master/doc/Ubuntu%20RT3290%20Bluetooth%20Host%20Driver%20User%20Guide.pdf             ...But i stopped at 3 because i could not work the .bin file.

Comment: Those directions are for 12.04, which is long since EOL. I'm not too surprised that those directions didn't work out of the box, but I'm not really sure what the solution is. Sorry.

Comment: I experienced a similar thing. I have several versions of Linux and I keep them on different drives. I noticed that Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3 kept crashing with no real pattern. I would change a cable it ran then hours later crashed. Nothing appeared to help. A few days ago doing an update by chance I saw there was a new video driver. Figuring that was easier then rebuilding the system I loaded it and it has not crashed since.

Comment: Would you happen to have a Ryzen processor? Update your question with processor, `free -h`, `sysctl vm.swappiness`, `swapon -s`, and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema No I have "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz ".
`free -h` : Mem:Total 7,7Gi used 2,0Gi free 3,1Gi shared 534Mi buff/cache 2,5Gi available 4,8Gi Swap: Total 2,0Gi used 0B free 2,0Gi ,`sysctl vm.swappiness`: vm.swappiness = 60 , `sweapon -s`: /swapfile   Type file    Seize 2097148 Size 0 priority -2

Comment: `ls -al /var/crash`:
total 63504 ,drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Απρ  16 14:01 . ,drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Μαρ  30 12:48 .. , -rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie  8715931 Απρ  13 23:02 , _opt_microsoft_msedge_msedge.1000.crash , -rw-r-----  1 root     whoopsie   121927 Απρ  11 18:48 rtbth-dkms.0.crash , -rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie        0 Απρ  11 18:48 rtbth-dkms.0.upload , -rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Απρ  11 18:49 rtbth-dkms.0.uploaded , -rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie  3716323 Απρ  16 14:01 _usr_bin_file-roller.1000.crash

Comment: , -rw-r-----  1 gdm      whoopsie   730048 Απρ  11 18:34 _usr_libexec_gnome-session-binary.125.crash , -rw-r-----  1 angelos  whoopsie 51716198 Απρ  12 22:49 _usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_opera_opera.1000.crash

Comment: Απρ is April and Μαρ is March

Comment: `sudo lshw -C memory` is a little to long . Do you want me to send it?

Comment: As you can see, putting any of that detailed output into comments is a mess. It all should have been an edit to your original question. Copy/paste the formatted output into your question, select the pasted text, then click the {} icon to format it to human-readable.

Comment: This looks like a memory problem. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete. Report back. Remember to start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard so I can check for a BIOS update for you.

Comment: @heynnema HP 15q-ds1000tu (6EW00PA) Laptop (Core i5 8th Gen/8 GB/256 GB SSD/Windows 10) ... Sorry for not responding to your previous message but i had some issues with `memtest` . In  `MemTest86_User_Guide_UEFI.pdf` page 6 I couldn't find <dev>.

Comment: @Runner Describe the `memtest` problem that you had. Please see my answer. Re-seat the memory SODIMM in its slot, re-run `memtest`, then do the BIOS update, then re-run `memtest`. Report back.

Comment: @Runner Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Sorry but I don't have much time these days to look at your reply . I will let you know as soon as I can

Comment: @Runner What problems did you have with `memtest`? Did it fail?

Comment: @Runner re: *"I don't have much time these days to look at your reply"*. Please remember that 1) you came here for help, and 2) I've spent significant time to research possible solutions to your problem. Please do what you can to find the time.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

HP 15q-ds1000tu (6EW00PA) Laptop

You have a very old BIOS version F.19 from 05/06/2019. There's a newer BIOS available, version F.38 Rev A, from Sep 7, 2021, available [here](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-15q-ds0000-laptop-pc/20395838/model/23565570).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your computer.

**Note**: Have good backups before performing the BIOS update.

**Memory**

Sounds like you have a memory (or BIOS) problem.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**Bluetooth**

It sounds like you've been having bluetooth issues. I need to get more details about this. I suspect that the bluetooth driver (rtbth-dkms) that you installed is incorrect, and will need to be removed.

reference: https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms/blob/master/doc/Ubuntu%20RT3290%20Bluetooth%20Host%20Driver%20User%20Guide.pdf

Show me `dkms status`.

**SWAP**

Let's bump your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: at `memtest` , page 6 of the user guide 2.2.4 how do I find the <dev> it is talking about. I used lsblk and put the output on the original question .

Comment: @Runner It's asking for the device associated with your USB flash drive. It must be plugged into a USB port for any command to see it. Be very careful with the `dd` command, 'cause if it's entered incorrectly, the results can be very bad. Read page 6 very carefully. You could probably also use `Startup Disk Creator`.

Comment: @Runner Status please...

Comment: `memtest` just finished . 100% tests passed. swap is also done and I haven't been able to enable my Bluetooth. "No bluetooth found "" plug in a dongle to use bluetooth"

Comment: The bluetooth part that you updated is what I think gave me these crashes when i followed the instructions about two weeks ago

Comment: @Runner Good job on `memtest`. I never gave you any instructions about your Bluetooth problem. We hadn't gotten that far. Did bluetooth ever work for you? Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `lspci -nnk`.

Comment: bluetooth worked on windows but has never worked on ubuntu

Comment: @Runner What version Ubuntu? Please show me the entire `dkms status` output. In the Bluetooth settings panel, is the OFF/ON switch at the top of the panel in the ON position? The rtbth dkms module that you tried to install never got fully installed. What made you decide to try and install that?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. That is the entire `dkms status`. It is in the OFF position. I thought that it would fix my Bluetooth problem

Comment: @Runner Did you flip the Bluetooth switch to the ON position and recheck your bluetooth? Please show me the entire `dkms status` output. What you gave was incomplete. Also show me `uname -r`.

Comment: @Runner What make/model is your computer?

Comment: The Bluetooth switch cant be turned on and that is actually the entire output of `dkms status`.

Comment: Do `sudo dkms remove rtbth/3.9.6 --all`, then `dkms status` should show nothing. Report back.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmesg | grep -i 'rtl | blue'`

Comment: both `dkms status` and `sudo dmesg | grep -i 'rtl | blue'` are empty. (I am searching for make model of my laptop.)

Comment: This may, or may not, help us... install `rtl8821ce-dkms`, and show me `dkms status`, reboot and retest BT. Make sure the BT is switched ON, if you can. If this doesn't help, we can uninstall it.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'rtl | blue'` (this command is slightly different than my earlier command).

Comment: @Runner Status please...

Comment: Installed `rtl8821ce-dkms` and i updated the `dkms status` command.  `sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'rtl | blue'` does not return anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135868/discussion-between-heynnema-and-runner).